# React, avoid re-rendering specific children component

Tags: reactjs

I have this tree of components:

```
Father
    Son
        Childrens
    Daughter
        Childrens2
    Modal
```

Everytime that Modal is open (by setting `this.setState({ openSimpleModal: true });`) or it's close (setting state as `false`) the componentes Son, Daughter, and their childrens components are re-rendered to. Is there a way where I can open and close the Modal, but not allowing to re-render 1 specific component, for example, `Son` (and their childrens) but re-rendering the rest? (Daughter, etc) but ONLY when the Modal opens or close. I need to render each child component in other scenarios, but I need to stop re-rendering when the Modal opens/close

What I tried is using

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps: Readonly<P>, nextState: Readonly<S>, nextContext: any): boolean {

    return this.state.openSimpleModal === nextState.openSimpleModal
}
```

and deciding if the state of the modal changed and in that case returns false, but it's not working, because of course the modal wont shows.

Comment: It depends on how you're rendering your component; could you show more of your Modal component? If it's not returning any elements when `openSimpleModal` is `false`, for example, there's no way to not re-render since it has to recreate the elements.

Comment: My understanding is that wehn openSimpleModal is set to false, Father will be dismounted and thus the other component will be dismounted as well? If it is dismounted, they all have to be re-rendered. If your concern is preserving the state, you should store the state in parent component. If your concern is performance, you need to think something else to optimize the rendering.

Answer (score 1):

In render slave the ChildComponent with the same boolean state?

```
class Father {

 render() {

  return (
    <div>
    {this.state.openSimpleModal &&  <ChildComponent />}
    <MyModal show={openSimpleModal} />
    </div>
  );
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. In your `shouldComponentUpdate` you are returning true when both are
   same so it updates. So it should rather be

   ```
   shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps: Readonly<P>, nextState: Readonly<S>, nextContext: any): boolean {

       return this.state.openSimpleModal != nextState.openSimpleModal
   }
   ```
2. There is no need to care about rerenders if it is not causing any performance issues.
3. You can use React.memo, React.PureComponent or React.useMemo based on your requirements

Comment: 1, But the state only changes when the Modal is triggered, the Father component will re-render in a lot of situations, but only when the state of the modal changes is when I don't want to get Father rendered. 2, The rerender is messing a small component that depends on the props of the Father component, but only in that case is where I do not want to pass the props from Father -> Son -> SmallComponent again. 3, thanks, I was reading yesterday about that, I will check more